# Progress Bars Not Executing in Order

Tags: vb.net, progress-bar

I am doing some decryption and I have two progress bars which are meant to run while the decryption is taking place, the second progress bar is meant to go  after the first progress bar is full. However, they both seem to go at the same time,
[a picture to show the action:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxuL6.png)

Furthermore, when I added message boxes to check the progress bars in each iteration they appeared to work fine, [a picture for that click here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4R39R.png)

Following is the code I used to assign values in the progress bars

```
Dim progress As integer
//Loop starts
//progress value added

     If progress > 0 And progress < 51 Then
          ProgressBar1.Value = progress
     ElseIf progress > 50 And progress < 101 Then
          ProgressBar2.Value = progress - 50
     End If

//Loop Ends
```

I am not sure why it is executing together, or appearing to execute together.

Is there any way for me to fix that?

Comment: Is there a chance you set ProgressBar1 = ProgressBar2 (or vice-versa)?

Comment: Hard to tell from the picture if they are actually the same value - it looks like they are a little different.  How is `progress` being incremented (e.g. 1, 2, 3 vs. 1, 37, 85 would make a big difference)?  Try adding `ProgressBar1.Value = 50` in the `ElseIf` block, to make sure that it is filled up when `progress` > 50.

Comment: The value of progress is (count / Len(cipher)) * 100, count = number of iterations, cipher = the text. This means that it's going up in like 1,3,4,6 on a short text or 1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4 on a long text, it's mainly dependant on the length

Comment: Someone answered and said to add ProgressBar1.PerformStep() and ProgressBar2.PerformStep() and this worked perfectly well, however it made the process 5 times slower. I think this why they deleted their post(maybe)

Comment: yes i deleted my answer, not because of it will make the process 5 times slower. if you want to use `.PerformStep()` you have to set `Step` property of ProgressBars properly.

Comment: Is there a way I can disable the controls from being changed programmatically?

Comment: `disable the controls from being changed programmatically?`  Not sure what that means.  Your loops probably need to run in a BackgroundWorker in order to update correctly on the screen.  The MessageBox version probably gives the screen a chance to refresh itself that the first version doesn't.

Comment: I meant it so the other won't go off. I did thought that the progress bars aren't updating so I tried putting a .Update or .Refresh after them but that made it worse so I ruled that thought out. I didn't know about Background worker and tried using it. However it comes up with "The background worker is busy" something like that, so I think the iteration isn't waiting for the worker to finish. I can use the RunWorkCompleted process but I'm not sure how to implement that in the loop without it going to the next counter.

Comment: We would have to see your looping code to help you.

Comment: If you found that PerformStep worked but is slow, then find a way to limit your updates to the progress bar. It only needs to be updated every second or so to be useful. Perhaps you can update on every nth time through the loop.

Comment: Thanks, that worked I used `If counter Mod 150 = 0` so the progress bars would step in every 150th iteration. I also figured out why the progress bars were behaving weirdly, it is because the iterations were so quick that they set the value of progress 100 and I _think_ the software updates it's controls every so seconds so I was noticing them filling up to 100, instead of regular intervals. I hope that made sense?